# Is there an iOS "Player Controller" for audio playback?

Tags: ios, audio, mp3, mpmovieplayercontroller

For video playback, I'm using MPMoviePlayerController, which provides a new user interface. Is there an equivalent for audio playback? I cannot get the MPMoviePlayerController to play an MP3 file.

Comment: (In the future consider asking the base question - "How can I play an audio file in iOS application?" - and then expand out. It would also make a better starting query in a search.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) might suit your needs. Although it does not provide the GUI elements in the way that MPMoviePlayerController does, it provides a high-level API that would be easy to combine with custom UI elements.

Additionally, you may be able to utilize Apple's sample project [avTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636) to see how it's used (or even include in your own project).